# Is there a plugin for limiting classes?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

Background story: some friends and I are thinking of hiring our own TF2 server. We want it to be public, and any players are welcome.

One thing that really bothers us in every game in current public servers is when a player suddenly decides that all snipers in the team are idiots and the team desperately needs a third sniper. Coincidence or not, that's when the team's performance goes down the drain, and the opposite team rolls over yours like a bulldozer.

The same could be said for teams with 3+ spies, that would be just as true.

**Is it possible to configure a TF2 server with a plugin to limit a team to at most 2 snipers and 2 spies?**

If so, how? What's the best plugin for this (a quick Google search shows hundreds, but we can't say how mature or buggy they are)? How easy is it for a bunch of beginners who have never administered a TF2 server to start?

*<Russian accent> [Many thanks!](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/9/97/Heavy_thanks02.wav)*

Comment: But all the snipers on the team always *are* idiots...

Answer (score 8):

For TF2, most of the plugins you're going to run into rely on a third-party scripting host.

One such popular scripting host is [SourceMod](http://www.sourcemod.net/) (and its base library, [MetaMod: Source](http://www.metamodsource.net/)).

SourceMod is [fairly simple](http://wiki.alliedmods.net/Installing_SourceMod) to install, but be warned: If you want some of its more advanced features, you need to [add admins](http://wiki.alliedmods.net/Adding_Admins_%28SourceMod%29).

Once you have SourceMod installed, you can get the [Class Restrictions mod](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=73104) from AlliedModders Forum.  This allows you to set how many of each class there is on each team.

Comment: Upvoted for this.  Sourcemod rocks, and the classrestrict plugin is simple and effective.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland: Yup.  I also have taken over the maintenance of a plugin and created my own, new one... specifically Mapchooser Extended for the former and its Sounds plugin for the latter.

Comment: Is this the mod that says "NO!" in the Heavy's voice when you try and pick an already-capped class?

Comment: @Raven Yep, that's the one.  We had it on our server for a long while.  Although I think it actually says "No" in the voice of whatever class you were trying to switch to.  Or it's supposed to, at least

Comment: I pretty much won't touch a non-sourcemod tf2 mod now.  The ease of use and review process just make server customization soooooo smooth.